# Check if value already exist in SQL

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I'd like to check if value entered in the php form already exist in MySQL database, and show message if same value is found, and ofc different message if no duplicate was found.
I used this code:

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT id FROM tb_cform WHERE u_email = '".$_POST['u_email']."'");
if($result->num_rows == 0) {
 echo'Mail address was not forund in database!'; 
} else {
die("Mail address already exist in the database!");
}
```

However, i keep getting the "else" part of the statement whatever email I enter, so I always get "Mail address already exist in the database!" message.

Any help please?

Comment: You had better show us the `<form>` as there does no seem to be anything obvious wrong with the query. Assuming you have used the correct names for tables and columns

Comment: It would be a good idea to Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks for your answer. I'm sure that form works okay, this is the input field for email: `<input type="email" class="form-control" name="u_email" required id="email" placeholder="jane.doe@example.com">`
Besides that, $_POST['u_email'] prints actually entered email, and "u_email" is correct name for database row, i triple-ckecked that.
I added code to generate errors, but nothing is showed besides message that email is already in the database.

Comment: @Strawberry I'd like to prevent users from entering the same email multiple times, that's why I'm performing this check.

Comment: There's no need to check first. In fact, its counterproductive. Instead, the checking should be incorporated into the INSERT. If the INSERT then fails, you know why,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, got it, I placed the whole code at the wrong place in file, it was placed after I actually run a query for adding the email in the database, and therefore check always returned that mail is found, my mistake, sorry!

Comment: It's still a flawed approach however.